# Python 3.7.3 error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pages'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest

After using the command in Windows 10 CMD(Command Prompt) C:\Users\my.name\PycharmProjects\PROJECTNAME\Tests>python -m unittest login.py

I got an error:

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: login
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\my.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\my.name\PycharmProjects\PROJECTNAME\Tests\login.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Pages.loginPage import LoginPage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pages'
```

My code structure:

```
PROJECTNAME
|-- Drivers
|-- Pages
|   |-- loginPage.py
|-- Tests
|   |-- login.py
```

login.py:

```
import unittest

from selenium import webdriver
from Pages.loginPage import LoginPage
import HtmlTestRunner
class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):





C:\Users\my.name\PycharmProjects\PROJECTNAME>python -m unittest Tests.login
```

command working fine, but why

```
C:\Users\my.name\PycharmProjects\PROJECTNAME\Tests>python -m unittest login.py
```

is not working and throwing an error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run from `C:\Users\my.name\PycharmProjects\PROJECTNAME` like

```
C:\Users\my.name\PycharmProjects\PROJECTNAME\>python -m unittest Test\login.py
```

If it does not work try relative import like

```
from ..Pages.loginPage import LoginPage
```

and run from `PROJECTNAME` directory